# Compressed Bloom Filters with fixed false positive probability

Tags: math, hash, bloom-filter

I am trying to implement compressed bloom filter implementation according to this paper [Compressed Bloom Filters by Michael Mitzenmacher](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/NEWWORK/postscripts/cbf2.pdf). I need to calculate *m* - number of bits and *k* - number of hash functions for given fixed false positive probability. For example:
I know that if I have **n** = 1000 elements(to be inserted in bloom filter) and given probability **p** = 0.01, the "optimal" number of bits will for Bloom filter will be `(-n * Math.log(p) / (Math.log(2) * Math.log(2)))` = 9585
And also I need **k** = (9585/1000)*Math.log(2) = 7 - hash functions. That is, I will get false positive rate 0.01.
To "compress" bloom filter we need to build more "sparse" filter - get lesser hash functions and more number of bits in vector. 
But I did not get the idea how to calculate number of hash functions and number of bits for this sparse filter. If we decrease k by 1 how will increase number of bits? what is the ratio?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try emailing the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did not find any concrete ratio between number of hash functions and number of bits with fixed false positive rate. But I have found precalculated table of such values. [Here](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~cao/papers/summary-cache/node8.html) you can find values of number of hash functions and bit vector length with corresponding false positive rate. Since we have such table we can find number of hash functions(less than optimal) and corresponding bit vector length with false positive rate less or equal to the given.
[Here](https://github.com/addthis/stream-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clearspring/analytics/stream/membership/BloomCalculations.java) is implementation for building "sparse" bloom filters.
Hope this will save someone`s time in future.